# Is it possible to get the full document being compared during Lucene sort

Tags: java, lucene

I am using `Lucene 5.5`.

I have a custom `FieldComparatorSource` class which is comparing a field using custom `TermValComparator`. This only let me compare that one field.

Is there a way to have a custom sorter which can get the whole document being compared for sorting?

Comment: what do you mean compare whole document? How the sorting would work in this case? Let's say you have 2 fields in document and sorting by document - how logic would work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, I just created a new index field with multiple data items to do custom sorting.